# How to automap a backend-agnostic Base in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, oracle, sqlalchemy

I am trying to take a simple database schema in Oracle and migrate it to a mssql database. There are other ways I can do this but my first thought was to utilize SQLAlchemy's automap and create_all functionality to do it pretty much instantaneously.

Unfortunately when I attempt to do so I run into some conversion errors:

Input:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from custom_connections import connect_to_oracle, connect_to_mssql

Base = automap_base()
oracle_engine = connect_to_oracle()
mssql_engine = connect_to_mssql()

Base.prepare(oracle_engine, reflect=True, schema = ‘ORACLE_MAIN_DB’)

Base.metadata.create_all(mssql_engine)
```

(Note that the connect_to functions are custom functions which return sqlalchemy engines. Currently they just return engines with base settings.)

Output:

```
CompileError: (in table 'acct', column 'acctnbr'): Compiler <sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.base.MSTypeCompiler object at 0x00000268E8FF6DA0> can't render element of type <class 'sqlalchemy.dialects.oracle.base.NUMBER'>
```

The issue is that while Sqlalchemy is converting most types to sqlalchemy types when mapping the Base, it doesn't do the same with Oracle NUMBER types. I attempted a similar trick using alembic autogeneration off the automapped Base, but the Oracle NUMBER types caused issues there as well.

Given all the power behind it, I would have thought Sqlalchemy would be able to handle this without any issues. Is there a technique or setting I could use when running this code which would cause it to convert all types to their Sqlalchemy equivalent when mapping the base instead of just most types?

Comment: The SQL Server Migration Assistant for Oracle is understands the Oracle-to-SQL Server type mapping, and allows you to customize the type mapping if you need to.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssma/oracle/sql-server-migration-assistant-for-oracle-oracletosql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Yeah it is a cool tool. I will probably use it if I can't make this work in Sqlalchemy, but I'm honestly curious if there is a way to do with in SQLAlchemy.

Answer (score 1):

This is described in the [SQLAlchemy docs about reflection](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/reflection.html#reflecting-with-database-agnostic-types):

```
from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Table, create_engine
from sqlalchemy import event

mysql_engine = create_engine("mysql://scott:tiger@localhost/test")
metadata_obj = MetaData()
my_mysql_table = Table("my_table", metadata_obj, autoload_with=mysql_engine)
# my_table should already exist in your db, this is the table you want to convert

@event.listens_for(metadata_obj, "column_reflect")
def genericize_datatypes(inspector, tablename, column_dict):
    column_dict["type"] = column_dict["type"].as_generic()

my_generic_table = Table("my_table", metadata_obj, autoload_with=mysql_engine)
# generic table will be a generic version of my_table
sqlite_eng = create_engine("sqlite:///test.db", echo=True)\
my_generic_table.create(sqlite_eng)
```

Comment: WIth this the table is reflected with the decorated metadata_obj. What I'd really like is to take a metadata object and return a transformed one that is all run through as_generic().